# Installtion of MVC website which uses Telerick Controls

Tags: telerik

We are building a reporting tool using MVC and Telerik controls. We usually deploy our product on a client's server. The client buys .net framework on his own. Now, our question is should the client buy a license for Telerik controls or will the dll we include be fine? We don't want to burden the client to buy a license just to see the website. Can someone please help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

If your company has purchased the telerik controls then it is ok to give telerik control dlls with publish.

also check what type of license you have purchased.

Comment: We are planning to buy  Dev Craft. We haven't bought it yet because we need to check about the client side licensing. If it  is a burden to client then he would not prefer our product .